# Use connection to db in another file

Tags: python, sql, database, orm

How can I use the initialized connection in python to the database in one file and use it in another file?

For example,
**db_connect.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column
from clickhouse_sqlalchemy import get_declarative_base, types, make_session

def get_connection(uri):
    engine = create_engine(uri)
    session = make_session(engine)
    return session
```

**main.py**

```
from db_connect import get_connection

uri = 'clickhouse://default:@*.*.*.*:8123/my_table'
session = get_connection(uri)
```

**connection_use.py**

```
# Here I want to use my initialized conneciton `session` 
a = session.query(...).filter_by(...)
```

I want to do it because the init process takes a lot of time, and I do queries many times in different places.
Maybe use this connection as a class? But I still init it in main.py

Comment: Set the global "session" variable not in "main.py" but in a module (better: in a function in a module). Then you can import the variable like you import functions (after it was initialized to the connection object).

Answer (score 0):

Move `session = get_connection(uri)` into db_connect.py (the end). This way session is initialized when db_connect is imported for the first time.

in connection_use.py:

```
from .db_connect import session

a = session.query(...)
```

Note: This is not the prettiest pythoniest way to do it, just the minimal changes to make your example work. Also the import statement assumes python 3 and db_connect in the same directory.